# Android ListView with EditText search

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

I am working on a app where I have listview with edittext search option on top. Below is my code for **`onTextChanged`**, I am getting an error **`cannot resolve method get(java.lang.String)`** Need help here.

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                          int count) {
    /*if (s.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
        initList();
    }else{
        searchItem(s.toString());
    }*/

    int textlength = editsearch.getText().length();
    ArrayList<String> listitems2 = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < listitems.size(); i++) {

        itemname[i] = listitems.get(i).get("itemname");
        Log.d("unm", itemname[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < listitems.size(); i++) {
        if (textlength <= itemname[0].length()) {


            if (itemname[i].toLowerCase().contains(
                    editsearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase().trim())) {
                listitems2.add(listitems.get(i));
            }
        }
    }
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Function.this, R.layout.list_funitem, R.id.txtitem, listitems2);

    mlist.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

I am getting error at following position "**.get("itemname")**"

```
itemname[i] = listitems.get(i).get("itemname");
```

Comment: TRY THIS : itemname[i] = listitems.get(i);

Comment: String class doesn't have get() method and what you get from ArrayList is String

Comment: this is wrong: inside `TextWatcher` methods you should just call `adapter.getFilter().filter(...)` to perform filtering, BTW you should use `afterTextChanged`, not `onTextChanged`

Comment: @pskink when I am clicking on filter array its not taking the correct position, it is taking the position of original list view

Comment: `ArrayAdapter` is `Filterable` so use it fo filter things out instead of setting a new adapter again and again

Comment: @pskink my issue is i have listview with n number of items, when i am selecting any particular item from listview it's going to next activity which is webview. But, when I am selecting item from filtered list it is going to next activity but it is picking wrong itemid

Comment: do you know `android.widget.Adapter#getItem` method? just use it

Comment: @pskink Thank you, it worked, I just added one line of code getItem and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> listitems2 = new ArrayList<String>();

for(int i=0;i<listitems.size();i++)
{

if(listitems.get(i).itemname.toLowerCase().contains(editsearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase()))
{
 listitems2.add(listitems.get(i));
}

}

  adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Function.this, R.layout.list_funitem, R.id.txtitem, listitems2);

    mlist.setAdapter(adapter);
```